# Adding an additional field to json4s structure

Tags: json4s

I'm trying to add an additional field to a json4s structure but documentation describes only removeField and transformField. Something like addField is missing.
So, the json input I have is this:

```
{
  "layers": [
    {
      "name": "geometry",
      "layerProperties": [
        {
          "name": "Schema-Layer",
          "value": "schema"
        },
        {
          "name": "Schema-Proto-Bundle",
          "value": "geometry"
        },
        {
          "name": "Compression",
          "value": "true"
        },
        {
          "name": "Content-Type",
          "value": "application/x-protobuf"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "schema",
      "layerProperties": [
        {
          "name": "Content-Type",
          "value": "application/zip"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "state",
      "layerProperties": [
        {
          "name": "Compression",
          "value": "true"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "history",
      "layerProperties": [
        {
          "name": "Content-Type",
          "value": "application/json"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

and I need to achieve this:

```
{
  "layers": [
    {
      "name": "geometry",
      "dataUrl": "s3://somebucket/somepath",
      "layerProperties": [
        {
          "name": "Schema-Layer",
          "value": "schema"
        },
        {
          "name": "Schema-Proto-Bundle",
          "value": "geometry"
        },
        {
          "name": "Compression",
          "value": "true"
        },
        {
          "name": "Content-Type",
          "value": "application/x-protobuf"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "schema",
      "dataUrl": "s3://somebucket/somepath",
      "layerProperties": [
        {
          "name": "Content-Type",
          "value": "application/zip"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "state",
      "dataUrl": "s3://somebucket/somepath",
      "layerProperties": [
        {
          "name": "Compression",
          "value": "true"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "history",
      "dataUrl": "s3://somebucket/somepath",
      "layerProperties": [
        {
          "name": "Content-Type",
          "value": "application/json"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

So, each layer needs to have a dataUrl fieldAny ideas?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to paste how I parse the file:
    def parseTemplate(templateFile: File): JValue = {
      var jsonStr: String = ""
      for (line <- scala.io.Source.fromFile(templateFile).getLines) jsonStr += line
      org.json4s.jackson.JsonMethods.parse(jsonStr, useBigDecimalForDouble = false)
    }